# Open .mdproj file in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I recently inherited a set of code that includes a .mdproj file.  After a bit of googling, I was able to determine this is a Mono Development project.  What I wasn't able to resolve was if this is meant to be opened in Visual Studio or not.  All of the other projects in the solution are C# projects.  So:

1. Is it possible to open a Mono Development project in VS2010?
2. If not, can I convert it to a C# project?
3. Should I use VS2010, or should I use MonoDevelop?

Any insight into this would be much appreciated.  I am not familiar with MonoDevelop.

**Edit:** Turns out that [Xamarin Studio](http://monodevelop.com/Download) cannot open the file either..back to googling.

**Update:**
Opening the file in a text editor reveals the following:

```
"General"
{
"SccProjectName" = "\"$/BNT_AVM/CAT/SRC/Enhancement/CATApp/CATAnalysisProject\", BYRCAAAA"
"SccLocalPath" = "."
"SccAuxPath" = ""
"SccProvider" = "MSSCCI:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe"
"ProjectIdGuid" = "{F7615CCA-82F9-41F8-BB04-367601CCBE8A}"
"ShowAllFiles" = "T"
}
"Configurations"
{
    "Debug|Win32"
    {
    }
    "Release|Win32"
    {
    }
}
"Folders"
{
}
"Files"
{
    "Model1.mdx"
    {
    "ProjRelPath" = "T"
    }
}
"ProjStartupServices"
{
}
"Globals"
{
}
```

Does anyone recognize the format?

Comment: Open the file in a file editor and make sure you know what is inside of it. An extension is meaningless, as anyone can use that extension.

Comment: @LexLi I have added the contents of the file after opening it in a text editor.  Do you recognize it?

Comment: I have provided you an answer and also removed monodevelop tag, as it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have pasted its content, then it is clear that this .mdproj file is a model project for [Rational XDE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21207769). It has nothing to do with MonoDevelop, though it uses .mdproj as file extension.

And the reference of Model1.mdx is a [UML model](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0731_kishore/).

Check the reference links and you will see where .mdproj and .mdx are mentioned.

However, IBM no longer develops Rational XDE. So you will have to migrate such projects according to IBM's recommendations,

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/products/xde/

Comment: Is this something that you already knew, or did you do some research to find the answer?  I ask because I would like to know how I could have found the answer with more research.

Comment: I simply did some research. The initial search shows that this Melton is shared by several products. That's why I asked you to post the file content. After that I could confirm it is not for MonoDevelop, as I have used it for a long time. And a search on mdx finally made everything linked together.